# Запятая при уточнении(?)

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте. Как правильно оформить предложение? 
Он прослушал сводки новостей(-) около полудюжины(,) одну за другой, пока не задремал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он прослушал сводки новостей - около полудюжины, одну за другой, - пока не задремал.

С помощью тире выделяем вставную конструкцию, запятая "перенесенная".

Comment: Спасибо большое